# Excel formula sumproduct consuming more time (EPPlus)

Tags: excel, epplus

I have a workbook, which contains 2 sheets.
comments and Summary

In comments sheet I have columns - category, type and status

- category takes string values like comments, security, control flow etc..
- type takes values as P or C
- status takes values as Y or N

In my summary, I have columns - category, P_type, C_Type, total_status

- category contains same strings as in comments sheet
- P_type - no of p-type of corresponding category
- C_type - no of c-type of corresponding category
- total_staus - no of Y's of corresponding category of P and C type

for that I have filled each cell with formulas as

```
if (j == 3)
{
    cellRange.Formula = "SUMPRODUCT((Comments!B:B=B" + i + ")*(Comments!D:D=\"P\"))";
}

if (j == 4)
{
    cellRange.Formula = "SUMPRODUCT((Comments!B:B=B" + i + ")*(Comments!D:D=\"C\"))";
}

if (j == 5)
{        
    cellRange.Formula = "SUMPRODUCT((Comments!B:B=B" + i + ")*(Comments!G:G=\"Y\"))";
}
```

Note: comments sheet gets filled using database and it can have any number of rows.
In summary sheet, column B contains category strings
In comments sheets, column D and Column G contains type and status respectively

whenever I open excel sheet or change any cell values in column type and status, it takes noticeable amount of time.
No of category is 14, so there are total 42 SUMPRODUCT formulas.

I have change the excel settings to use all processors; in my system 8 are available.

any suggestions to reduce these sumproduct calculations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added row limit in the search range for each formula. Now there is a significant change in time.
Much better.

```
 cellRange.Formula = "SUMPRODUCT((Comments!B7:B"+nTotalRows+"=B" + i + ")*(Comments!D7:D"+nTotalRows+"=\"P\"))";
```